# Can a user with /sbin/nologin shell login through ssh?

Tags: ssh, security, login

Is it possible to ssh to a machine as a user with no valid shell (say, `mail`)? So far I cannot, and using the command below doesn't work:

```
$ ssh mail@machine.local /bin/bash
```

It will always say "This account is currently not available.". But if I'm logged-in to the machine and use 'su'

```
$ su mail -s /bin/bash
```

I can become user `mail`.

Answer (score 5):

The command passed to `ssh` is run by the shell on the server, so if no valid shell is specified then it is not possible to run it.

Comment: @Ignacio: Makes sense...but are there any known workaround to this?

Comment: You could use a key and put an entry in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to allow executing a different command.

Comment: @Ignacio: I fail to see how adding another way to authorize a user changes the shell being launched on login.  And if `mail` has no `$HOME`, where would you put a key?

Comment: @Alex: **mail** has a **$HOME** it's /var/spool/mail. So I tried @Ignacio's suggestion to put an ssh key but it's not being accepted by the server.